# Updating system app without root and apk install in stock ROM

Tags: updates, system-apps, stock-rom

I need to update system apps like phone, contacts etc without installing apk or rooting. Is this possible?

*Stock ROM in Moto X4*

How can I update my phone, contact etc with latest version from moto? Is this only possible by OTA? I have seen in xiaomi devices which provide updates to system apps without OTA.

Comment: Please ask two separate questions as they are distinct. For Moto you can simply update those apps from Play Store. It worked that way on Moto X Play

Comment: Phone and contact app is not listed on play store for updates. It's not Google's phone and contact. But, messages is of Google's and updated to latest version.

Comment: In that case it is a system app of Moto and you **need OTA**.